# difference between "self" and "root" in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

What is the difference between self and root in kivy?
I couldn't clear my doubt with info provided on kivy official website.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

As specified over [the docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html)

> `self` The keyword self references the “current widget instance”:

> `root` This keyword is available only in rule definitions and represents the root widget of the rule
> (the first instance of the rule):

in the definition example below:

```
<MyWidget>:
    custom: 'Hello world'
    Button:
        text: root.custom
```

`root` refers to `<MyWidget>` widget, so `root.custom` evaluates to `'Hello world'`

Answer (score 1):

**self** - references to the current widget instance

**root** - references to the root widget instance (top layout)

**app** - references to the app instance

Answer (score -1):

**root** represents the top widget in the rule and **self** represents the current widget

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).